# Why did Light want to kill Near?

Tags: death-note

In Episode 37/Chapter 106, Light wants to kill Near. But what was his plan? Why did he want to kill Near? Was this because he was angry and wanted to kill the one who was responsible for his capture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By that point in time, Light wanted to kill anyone who threatened or insulted him (though he would not really want to admit the latter one).  His ego and desensitization had risen to the point that he did not not really care who he killed.  Near claimed to be L's true heir and the one who could bring Kira (as known as L now and also known as Light) down.  Of course he wanted to kill him.

I don't think he would have seriously entertained any other idea at that time even if he bothered to come up with it.  He was more inthralled with his godhood than even the battle anymore.

Note: I don't think it mattered that at episode 37 (the last episode) that even after killing Near, he would still be captured.  He wanted to kill Near because he insulted/threatened him.  If he could avoid capture, though, he would have probably done that planning on killing him later.

Comment: His plan was to write his name in the Death Note page in his watch. Maybe they wouldn't notice in time or hesitate to shoot him? Didn't work.

Comment: In chapter 106 (i just read it again) light planed to kill Near to convince the other into letting him free. @kaine

Comment: Was that is Episode 37 too? don't have the manga and didn't remember that statement.  In either case, he came to the meeting intending to kill him and he wanted to kill him due to the events there.  If he thought killing him would increase his chance of survival even slightly, it is obvious that would just add to his reason for trying to kill him.

Comment: Yeah he said it in chapter 106. You can read the manga at mangafox.com @kaine

Comment: FYI (only because I didn't at first), mangafox isn't legal. Its not on crunchyroll (which is).  I based my answer on the anime (and your question implied either). If an answer comes along who can answer better for manga, accept his.

Comment: Hey, don't insult me. I didn't knew that mangafox is illegal. @kaine

Comment: Wasnt an insult. I didnt know at first as it had a legal disclaimer and i said it in case you didnt know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17787/discussion-between-darkyagami-and-kaine).